# build protobuf for android

Tags: android, android-ndk, protocol-buffers, cross-compiling, automake

Refer to other one's topic, I do:

```
export ANDROID_ROOT=/home/jean/android-ndk-r8e
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_ROOT/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.7/prebuilt/linux-x86/bin/
./configure --host=arm-linux-androideabi CC=arm-linux-androideabi-gcc CPPFLAGS="-I$ANDROID_ROOT/platforms/android-9/arch-arm/usr/include/ -I$ANDROID_ROOT/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.7/include" CFLAGS="-nostdlib" LDFLAGS="-Wl,-rpath-link=$ANDROID_ROOT/platforms/android-9/arch-arm/usr/lib/ -L$ANDROID_ROOT/platforms/android-9/arch-arm/usr/lib/" LIBS="-lc"
```

Configure success, but make report error, it says can not find bits/c++config.h in include path, I search this file, found it located in android-ndk-r8e/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.7/libs/armeabi/include/bits, so I copy it to android-ndk-r8e/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.7/include and make again, another error:

```
/bin/bash ../libtool  --tag=CXX   --mode=compile arm-linux-androideabi-g++ -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I..   -I/home/jean/android-ndk-r8e/platforms/android-9/arch-arm/usr/include/ -I/home/jean/android-ndk-r8e/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.7/include  -Wall -Wwrite-strings -Woverloaded-virtual -Wno-sign-compare -O2 -g -DNDEBUG -MT common.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/common.Tpo -c -o common.lo `test -f 'google/protobuf/stubs/common.cc' || echo './'`google/protobuf/stubs/common.cc
libtool: compile:  arm-linux-androideabi-g++ -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I.. -I/home/jean/android-ndk-r8e/platforms/android-9/arch-arm/usr/include/ -I/home/jean/android-ndk-r8e/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.7/include -Wall -Wwrite-strings -Woverloaded-virtual -Wno-sign-compare -O2 -g -DNDEBUG -MT common.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/common.Tpo -c google/protobuf/stubs/common.cc  -fPIC -DPIC -o .libs/common.o
../libtool: line 1125: arm-linux-androideabi-g++: command not found
make[2]: *** [common.lo] Error 1
```

This is weird, I have add arm-linux-androideabi-g++ path to PATH and I input "arm-linux-androideabi-g++ --version" it works, why make can not find it?

BTW
the configure will report error if I execute it with sudo or change to super user. The error is:

```
checking for arm-linux-androideabi-gcc... arm-linux-androideabi-gcc
checking whether the C compiler works... no
configure: error: in `/home/jean/Dev/cpplibs/protobuf-2.5.0':
configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add:

```
CXX=arm-linux-androideabi-g++
```

at least to your arguments to `configure`.  You may need to ad some `CXXFLAGS` as well.

Comment: still same result. The same commands I try on my macbook is OK

Comment: I am having a little prob with this. @Idav1s can you chat?